# .htaccess - If/Else redirect depending on query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Setting up an .htaccess seems to be difficult for this situation. For a dating site we have this scenario:

```
We assume john is logged in:

domain.com/john //this works no problem

domain.com/?askout=yes&when=later //this doesn't work, if john is logged in and pastes 
                                    this url, it automatically redirects to domain.com/john
                                    instead, htaccess should see the ? and know it's
                                    not a valid user. It should keep the entire query,
                                    and redirect to /profiles.php?askout=yes&when=later
```

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./profiles.php?username=$1
```

Basically, I need to have .htaccess know that an immediate ? means not to use the above rewrite rule. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} askout=yes&when=later
RewriteRule ^ /profiles.php?askout=yes&when=later [L]
```

This rule needs to go *before* the rule you have redirecting to the `?username` target.

Answer (score 0):

You need a RewriteCond I think: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html, with which you can do all manner of checks